# Heroku Rails project location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've deployed my Rails application to Heroku following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 and can open a website like http://severe-mountain-793.herokuapp.com

Now I'm quite confused: where is the app actually stored? What would the variable `Rails.root` of the app be? If I run a system command `system(...)` in my controller, where is it run from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby you can always do `Dir.pwd` to find out what context you are in. You could do this from within the context of your app with `heroku run console` to get a remote console on your local machine.

In addition, you can SSH directly into the server by running `heroku run bash`. I think you will find your app is stored off the root directory in `/app`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm... so if I want to download a file onto the `public` folder using `wget`, what should the location be? Should it be `Rails.root.join('public/...')` or just `/public/...`, or what?

Comment: Yes, base everything off `Rails.root.join('public', 'path', 'to', 'file.txt')`. The public folder lives within the app.